# Sending Current Variable Value through a Link

Tags: php

I have a table that is generated from data inside of a database.
Each row of the table is one row of my database. At the end of each row I create a link to start the process of removing the data from the table and database. Here is a snip of my code:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>".$row["username"]."</th>";
        $user = $row["username"];
        echo "<th>".$row["name"]."</th>";
        $name = $row["name"];
        echo "<th><a href='./test.php'.urlencode($user)>Remove</a></th>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}
```

As you can see, once the link is clicked I want to run `test.php` with the variable (and its value for that row) already set. Ive attempted to do this with `urlencode` but when doing a `echo $user`, it returns as undefined variable. I have also tried `echo "<th><a href='./test.php?link='$user>Remove</a></th>";`.
I would like to be able to send up to 6 variables with values.

**EDIT 1:**
Here is a picture of one row from my table:
[image]

The first two columns are username and name. You can see that the values are set and displayed within the `while` loop. I would like each iteration of the loop to create a unique link to remove that row from the database. Or simply for this case, send the data values for that row when the link is clicked.

Comment: I think you want to do something like this: `echo "<th><a href='./delete.php?user=$row["username"]'>Remove</a></th>";`

Comment: If `$user` is undefined, then `$row["username"]` should be as well undefined - try `print_r($row)` to see what's really inside

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`http_build_query`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) function:

```
$qs = [
    'user' => $row["username"],
    'name' => $row["name"],
    // ... 4 more values
];
echo '<th><a href="test.php?' . http_build_query($qs, null, '&amp;', PHP_QUERY_RFC3986) . '">Remove</a></th>';
```

Comment: what would be the best way to retrieve these values once in `test.php`?

Comment: The values will be populated in: `$_GET['user']` and `$_GET['name']`

Answer (score 0):

You are not defining the variable name in your link. The line

```
echo "<th><a href='./test.php'.urldecode($user)>Remove</a></th>";
```

should look like

```
echo "<th><a href='./test.php?user=".urlencode($user)."&name=".urlencode($name)."'>Remove</a></th>";
```

then, in your test.php file you will read those variables with `$_GET['user']` and `$_GET['name']`.

Also, beware that in your original code, you are using `urldecode` instead of `urlencode`

Comment: `urlencode` should not be used in this context; in the context of URL you should use [`rawurlencode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php). `http_build_query` is the better option though.

Comment: Yes, definitely `http_build_query` is a much better choice.